# AAB appstore install crashes on physical device, but download the APK available and it's fine

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, google-play-console, eas

Not sure what the next steps are after days of trying to debug.

I am using Expo & EAS to create my builds.  Everything is great on iOS. After local testing on emulator & physical device on Android, I manually upload the AAB file to PlayStore.  It gets approved & I start the "closed testing" track.  I have my test user account signed in to Google Play store on my **physical** device.  I get the link from Google for testing and Successfully install on my device.  As soon as I open app it crashes.

The `logcat` logs are pretty mysterious to me.

```
 V  ANGLE Developer option for 'com.identafly.production' set to: 'default'
2023-11-12 23:15:15.552 24656-24656 GraphicsEnvironment     pid-24656                            V  ANGLE GameManagerService for com.identafly.production: false
2023-11-12 23:15:15.816 24656-24656 LoaderFiles             pid-24656                            E  Failed to copy asset null
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResource(ResourcesImpl.java:341)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1387)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1331)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderFiles.copyResourceAndGetHash$expo_updates_release(LoaderFiles.kt:67)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderFiles.copyAssetAndGetHash(LoaderFiles.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.EmbeddedLoader.loadAsset(EmbeddedLoader.kt:80)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.downloadAllAssets(Loader.kt:233)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.processUpdateManifest(Loader.kt:196)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.access$processUpdateManifest(Loader.kt:25)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader$start$1.onSuccess(Loader.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.EmbeddedLoader.loadManifest(EmbeddedLoader.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.start(Loader.kt:98)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.launchFallbackUpdateFromDisk(LoaderTask.kt:261)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.start(LoaderTask.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:331)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:506)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:41)
                                                                                                        at com.identafly.production.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6910)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2219)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8061)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:703)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
2023-11-12 23:15:15.816 24656-24656 Loader                  pid-24656                            E  Failed to download asset with key 8b1af259f13def23641ece26e56ba436
                                                                                                    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:226)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.openRawResource(ResourcesImpl.java:341)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1387)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1331)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderFiles.copyResourceAndGetHash$expo_updates_release(LoaderFiles.kt:67)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderFiles.copyAssetAndGetHash(LoaderFiles.kt:34)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.EmbeddedLoader.loadAsset(EmbeddedLoader.kt:80)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.downloadAllAssets(Loader.kt:233)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.processUpdateManifest(Loader.kt:196)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.access$processUpdateManifest(Loader.kt:25)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader$start$1.onSuccess(Loader.kt:108)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.EmbeddedLoader.loadManifest(EmbeddedLoader.kt:58)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.start(Loader.kt:98)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.launchFallbackUpdateFromDisk(LoaderTask.kt:261)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.LoaderTask.start(LoaderTask.kt:118)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController.start(UpdatesController.kt:331)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesController$Companion.initialize(UpdatesController.kt:506)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.UpdatesPackage$createReactNativeHostHandlers$handler$1.onWillCreateReactInstanceManager(UpdatesPackage.kt:46)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:27)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager(ReactNativeHost.java:41)
                                                                                                        at com.identafly.production.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:67)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1266)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6910)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mhandleBindApplication(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2219)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8061)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:703)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)
2023-11-12 23:15:15.907 24656-24656 Loader                  pid-24656                            E  Failed to load all assets
                                                                                                    java.lang.Exception: Failed to load all assets
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.handleAssetDownloadCompleted(Loader.kt:303)
                                                                                                        at expo.modules.updates.loader.Loader.access$handleAssetD...
```

Inside the GoogleConsole bundle details, I noticed I can download the APK directly (which was generated from the AAB).  So I ran that app successfully on **physical device**!

I also tried installing from the AppStore on the emulator, and it worked fine.

What is the difference between the AAB and the app store direct install?  If it's installed correctly, wouldn't the link install be the same as the direct APK?